# depending on condition show error message in php

Tags: php

i have code like this

```
<?php 
require('../config.php'); 
require_once($CFG->dirroot . '/user/editlib.php');

$errorMessage = ''; 
$successMessage = ''; 
if(isset($_SESSION['successMessage'])) 
{ 
$successMessage = $_SESSION['successMessage']; 
unset($_SESSION['successMessage']); 
} 

if (isset($_POST['register'])) {

if(!preg_match("/^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(\S+)$/i", $_POST['password']))
{
  $errorMessage="don't allow spaces";
} 
$errors = array(); 
$data = array(); 
$chk_sql = "SELECT * FROM {user} u where username = ?"; 
if (!empty($chk_sql) ) {
    $errorMessage='Username already taken';
    }
if(!$chk_username = $DB->get_record_sql($chk_sql, array($_POST['username'])) ) 
{ 
$secret = $_POST['secret']; 
$access_code_sql = "SELECT * FROM {accesscode} WHERE random_no= ?  and status=1"; 
if($chk_secret = $DB->get_record_sql($access_code_sql, array($secret)) ) 
{ 

if ( $chk_secret->used >= $chk_secret->number ) { 
$errorMessage = "your access code limit completed..";
}

else
{
$cadminid = $chk_secret->cadmin_id; 
$clientid = $chk_secret->clientid; 
$DB->execute("UPDATE {accesscode} SET used = used+1 WHERE random_no = '$secret'"); 

$insert_record = new stdClass(); 
$insert_record->firstname = $_POST['firstname']; 
$insert_record->lastname = $_POST['lastname']; 
$insert_record->username = $_POST['username']; 
$insert_record->secret = $secret; 
$insert_record->password = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT); 
$insert_record->timecreated = time(); 
$insert_record->maildigest = $cadminid; 
$insert_record->maildisplay = $clientid; 
$insert_record->idnumber = 1; 
$insert_record->mnethostid = 1; 
$insert_record->confirmed = 1; 
$insert_record->email = $_POST['email']; 
if($result = $DB->insert_record('user', $insert_record)) 
{ 
$_SESSION['successMessage'] = "record created successfully"; 
header('Location: register.php'); 
} 
else 
$errorMessage = "error! can you please try again"; 
}
 }
else
$errorMessage = "your access code is wrong..";
}
} 
?>
```

so i want to write condition like another if condition

```
if ( $chk_secret->status='0' ) { 
$errorMessage = "your access code deactivated..";
}
```

if not they can register

i tried..but i didn't get idea where i have to add that if..

before i have condition like  if number>used it will show some error message like your accesscode limit completed

can anyone help me..

thanks in advance..

Comment: `if ( $chk_secret->status='0' )` that is an assignment and will always be considered as 0.

Comment: no actually i have one column in database status while they adding the status column is 1..

Comment: Typo.  You're using `=` instead of `==`.

Comment: so in my application i am not gng to delete the record i am just updating the record status to 0..so if it is 0 i want to show like that

Comment: @David ok..can you please tell me where i have to use that if in my page

Comment: @user3663: Where do you *want* to add it?  Where in your current logic would it be applied?  Define what you want your code to do, add the code which does it.  When you *try*, does it fail in some way?

Comment: if that if condition satisfies it has to throw error,,orelse it has to register user

Comment: @user3663: Well, you *already have* code which checks for conditions and produces an error message.  Maybe it would go near those?  It might actually be worth your time to open your code in an editor, *type some code into that editor*, save it, and test it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=` is for value assignment 
`==` is  compare two operands

so you need to change

```
if ( $chk_secret->status='0' ) {
```

to

```
if ( $chk_secret->status=='0' ) {
```

UPDATE:

your query `SELECT * FROM {accesscode} WHERE random_no= ?  and status=1`

which means it going to return only status == 1

you can check with number of rows returned is ZERO then through status zero error message.

Or else

Get rows only based on random_no exists and then check status key

Comment: ok.can you please tell me where i have to add this line in my page

Comment: no that query is fine..i need to write another condition. like if status zero

Comment: can you please tell me how?

Comment: @user3663 please check my ans properly... if you use the same query there is no chance of getting status 0 rows

Comment: yes..yes i understand..i need to fetch the records where status is zero and i have to  check condition right?

Comment: fetch records where random_no = ?, then use if conditions

Comment: ok can i use this if condition like this if ( $chk_secret->used >= $chk_secret->number&status='1' )

Comment: right  if ( $chk_secret->used >= $chk_secret->number && status=='1' )

Comment: so i can write another if condition right below that if condition right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155342/discussion-between-krish-and-user3663).